# what is ARCIMSG parameter in jcl2?

Tags: jcl

I have ARCIMSG parameter in my EXEC JCL job. I could not find anything about it in the documents. Could you please tell me where and why I used it ? You can find a sample code below.

Regards
Alper

```
 //VVD0212  EXEC ARCIMSG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is name of the **PROCEDURE** (cataloged or instream) that is to be executed.

If it is instream it will be coded within the JOB itself.

If it is cataloged then the procedure will be in one of the accessible libraries and the member name will be **ARCIMSG**. If the JCL includes a JCLLIB statement then that may indicate the library.

The **ARCIMSG** procedure will contain JCL that is included (copied in) at this point.